# Problema en cambiar un valor en access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Se trata de una tabla que muestra distinta información una de ella es que muestra una fecha de ingreso, pero en esa tabla a veces me cambia el formato por mes. dia y año y yo quiero dd-MM-YY. Hay alguna forma de cambiar el formato en la consulta he estado probando todo tipo de cosas y no hay forma... siempre me sale error. La fecha que se quiere cambiar formato es [data ingres]

```
sql="SELECT Numero,codi,[data ingres], data_alta, Nom,Cognoms,camp1 FROM [Dades Pacient] WHERE activat is null "&altres&" "&ordenar
```

%>

Comment: `SELECT Numero, codi, format([data ingres], "dd-mm-yy"), data_alta,  Nom, Cognoms, camp1 FROM...;` Si no funciona, imprime tu `sql` completa y revísala, no sea que tengas error de sintaxis en otra parte.

Comment: Buenas gracias por responder! Pero lo he probado y no hay manera... me da error 500.

Comment: El error 500 es un error del servidor, no de la base de datos. Puede ocurrir hasta por un símbolo de más o de menos en cualquier parte del código.

Comment: mm vale pero solo me da ese error cuando modifico eso... pero bno revisare a ver que puede ser. Gracias!

Comment: Prueba a quitarle los `[...]` en `[data ingres]` y en `[Dades Pacient]`

Comment: Nada me sigue saltando error 500. :/

Comment: ¿Y si pruebas la consulta en Access directamente sale error también?